# Setting page number in pdf generate using dataExporter(primefaces)

Tags: java, primefaces

```
<p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="callRpt"preProcessor="#{pc_CallReportBean.preProcessPDF}"
        fileName="#{reportLbl['callReport.callsReportFileName']}" />

public void preProcessPDF(Object document) throws IOException, BadElementException, DocumentException 
{  
    Document pdf = (Document) document;  
    pdf.open();  
    pdf.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);  

    ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext)FacesContext.
               getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();  
    String logo = servletContext.getRealPath("") + File.separator + "images" + File.separator + "prime_logo.png";  

    pdf.add(Image.getInstance(logo));  
}
```

in above code we export our table in pdf format using primefaces's tag 
and i set the logo in front page.

How can i set page-number,header,and footer using p:dataExporter ?

And also want to set table headings in every page if more than 1 pages are generate ?

Comment: Under the hood you are using iText as Document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I'm supposing you are using iText as PDF generator, you should implement the `PdfPageEventHelper` to create your headers and footers. With this function you will be able to increment page number in each page footer.

Here is a complete [example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=103) that show how to implement it.

Comment: sorry man i use lowagie as PDF generator.. I like that example but sorry i can't like your example B'coz i have not yet 15 reputation and for liking any answer i have 15 reputation required.. so really very very sorryyyyyyyy.  and please send me another example with lowagie if you wish...

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA iText IS the PDF Generator by Bruno Lowagie... indeed maybe you are running on the older version, what is your version?

Comment: thank's man now i jump to iText for generation of pdf..If any query are there how can i contect you...?B'coz i'm fresh to use iTextpdf..

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA Just post questions here! If I see questions that I can answer I'll do, if not, someone else will! Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it is the case, so people will know!

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA you should mark this as answered if it is the case!